# Is chain link a stand alone blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

Is chain link a stand alone blockchain or is it a series of smart contracts on the ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, It is an Oracle Provider, which allows you to access your oracle data to Smart Contract.

Comment: So the chainlink smart contracts connecting with ethereum smart contracts are also running on the ethereum blockchain?

Comment: yes, there are smart contracts that are running on Ethereum.